# Cannot choose between the following variants of org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:21

Tags: java, gradle, javafx

I'm writing an application using JavaFX and when I try to download sources I'm getting this error after upgrading to `id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'`:

```
Execution failed for task ':ijDownloadSourceseac56644-f3d'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':downloadSources_d8a57fab-051b-40e6-9c30-2d1f5d9d5ae1'.
   > Could not resolve org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:21.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Cannot choose between the following variants of org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:21:
          - linux-aarch64Runtime
          - linuxRuntime
          - mac-aarch64Runtime
          - macRuntime
          - runtime
          - winRuntime
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'linux-aarch64Runtime' capability org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:21:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides org.gradle.category 'library' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.native.architecture 'aarch64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.native.operatingSystem 'linux' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.status 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'linuxRuntime' capability org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:21:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides org.gradle.category 'library' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.native.architecture 'x86-64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.native.operatingSystem 'linux' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.status 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'mac-aarch64Runtime' capability org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:21:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides org.gradle.category 'library' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.native.architecture 'aarch64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.native.operatingSystem 'macos' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.status 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'macRuntime' capability org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:21:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides org.gradle.category 'library' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.native.architecture 'x86-64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.native.operatingSystem 'macos' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.status 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'runtime' capability org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:21:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides org.gradle.category 'library' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.status 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it
          - Variant 'winRuntime' capability org.openjfx:javafx-fxml:21:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides org.gradle.category 'library' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.libraryelements 'jar' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.native.architecture 'x86-64' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.native.operatingSystem 'windows' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.status 'release' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides org.gradle.usage 'java-runtime' but the consumer didn't ask for it

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.5/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
BUILD FAILED in 111ms
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I'm trying to fix that as per [plugin page](https://github.com/openjfx/javafx-gradle-plugin?tab=readme-ov-file#variants) but no luck so far. Can you please help me to understand why the **osConfiguration** configuration is not applied? Gradle import is successfull, but I'm still getting the above error. I'm totally lost now :(

This is my build.gradle:

```
import org.openjfx.gradle.JavaFXPlatform

plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.12'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.1.0'
    id "com.google.osdetector" version "1.7.3"
    id 'org.beryx.jlink' version '3.0.1'
    id "io.freefair.lombok" version "8.6"
}

group 'io.github.vcvitaly'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    junitVersion = '5.10.2'
    platform = getPlatform()
}

configurations {
    osConfiguration
}

java {
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
}

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.encoding = 'UTF-8'
}

application {
    mainModule = 'io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp'
    mainClass = 'io.github.vcvitaly.k8cp.HelloApplication'
}

javafx {
    version = JavaVersion.VERSION_21
    modules = ['javafx.controls', 'javafx.fxml']
}

dependencies {
    implementation('org.controlsfx:controlsfx:11.1.2')
    implementation('net.synedra:validatorfx:0.4.0') {
        exclude(group: 'org.openjfx')
    }
    implementation('org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-javafx:12.3.1')
    implementation 'org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-fontawesome-pack:12.3.1'
    implementation 'org.kordamp.ikonli:ikonli-fontawesome5-pack:12.3.1'
    implementation('org.kordamp.bootstrapfx:bootstrapfx-core:0.4.0')

    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.5.2'
    implementation 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.12'
    implementation 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.5.2'

    implementation ("io.kubernetes:client-java:20.0.0") {
        exclude group: "com.google.code.findbugs", module: "jsr305"
        exclude group: "com.amazonaws", module: "aws-java-sdk-sts"
    }

    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:${junitVersion}"
    testImplementation "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:${junitVersion}"
    testRuntimeOnly "org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:${junitVersion}"

    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:5.11.0'
    testImplementation "org.assertj:assertj-core:3.25.1"

}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

jlink {
    imageZip = project.file("${buildDir}/distributions/app-${javafx.platform.classifier}.zip")
    options = ['--strip-debug', '--compress', '2', '--no-header-files', '--no-man-pages']
    launcher {
        name = 'app'
    }
}

jlinkZip {
    group = 'distribution'
}

configurations.osConfiguration {
    attributes {
        attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Usage, Usage.JAVA_RUNTIME))
        attribute(OperatingSystemFamily.OPERATING_SYSTEM_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(OperatingSystemFamily, platform.osFamily))
        attribute(MachineArchitecture.ARCHITECTURE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(MachineArchitecture, platform.arch))
    }
}

def getPlatform() {
    return JavaFXPlatform.detect(osdetector);
}
```

Comment: The plugin page I believe is talking about Gradle being unable to choose a variant for JavaFX _binaries_. Your issue is with downloading the _sources_. Note I've run into the same problem when trying to get IntelliJ to download sources in a Gradle-based JavaFX project using the `org.openjfx.javafxplugin:0.1.0` plugin. Was unable to fix it directly at the time. Also not sure I understand Gradle variants enough to understand why your answer works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far was able to resolve it:

```
configurations
        .matching(it -> it.name.contains("downloadSources"))
        .configureEach {
    attributes {
        attribute(Usage.USAGE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(Usage, Usage.JAVA_RUNTIME))
        attribute(OperatingSystemFamily.OPERATING_SYSTEM_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(OperatingSystemFamily, platform.osFamily))
        attribute(MachineArchitecture.ARCHITECTURE_ATTRIBUTE, objects.named(MachineArchitecture, platform.arch))
    }
}
```